# Segmentation fault while working with decrement in for loop

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, matrix, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to implement a function in c++ that calculates a score matrix with the Needleman-Wunsch algorithm in reverse but I'm getting a segmentation fault 11.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int w(char x, char y){
        if (x == y){return 0;
        }else{return 1;
        }
    };

void compute_SM(std::string const & seq1, std::string const & seq2)
{

    int ws_cases[3];

    std::string m_seq1 = seq1 + " ";
    std::string m_seq2 = seq2 + " ";

    std::vector<int> rows(m_seq1.size(),0);
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(m_seq2.size(), rows);

    for (int i = 1; i< m_seq1.size(); i++){rows[i] = i*1;};
    for (int i = 1; i< m_seq2.size(); i++){matrix[0][i] = i*1;};

    for (unsigned int j = m_seq1.size()-1;j >= 1; j--){
        for (unsigned int i = m_seq2.size()-1;i  >= 1; i--){
            ws_cases[0] = matrix[i+1][j+1] + w(m_seq1[j],m_seq2[i]);
            ws_cases[1] = matrix[i+1][j] + 1;
            ws_cases[2] = matrix[i][j+1] + 1;
            matrix[i][j] = *std::max_element(ws_cases, ws_cases+3);
        }
    }

}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    compute_SM("BANANAS", "BANDS");
}
```

Comment: `int i = 1` looks fishy. Indexing starts at `0` in c++.

Comment: usually yes, but in this case i do not need to overwrite the value on the 0 index

Comment: What is `i*1` for?

Comment: Can you give us [something compilable](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d02ea77d52b374b)  please. In other words a [MCVE] is required to ask here.

Comment: What do you believe `=>` means?

Comment: Ask yourself if it is possible for `i` or `j` to ever be less than 0.

Comment: Shouldn't it be std::max_element(ws_cases, ws_cases + **3** );?

Comment: yes, changed it in the code below !

Comment: You have an out-of-range dereference `matrix[i+1]` in the first iteration, when `i` is `m_seq2.size()-1`.  And other errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Needleman-Wunsch algorithm, but after a quick look at the code you posted, the segmentation fault at the line

```
ws_cases[0] = matrix[i+1][j+1] + w(m_seq1[j],m_seq2[i]);
```

Happens at the very first iteration of the loops, when `j = m_seq1.size()-1`, `i = m_seq2.size()-1` and so `i + 1` and `j + 1` are out of bounds. Moreover, iterating in that way, those values are uninitialized.

Also, looking at the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm), it seems that you should put the space before your strings:

```
std::string m_seq1{" " + seq1};  
std::string m_seq2{" " + seq2};
```

Answer (score 0):

you have declared j as unsigned int, and suppose m_seq1.size() = 0, in this case, 
m_seq1.size() -1= 0-1=-1 ie; unsigned int j = -1, which can lead to run time segmentation fault.

```
 for (unsigned int j = m_seq1.size()-1;j => 0; j--) //.j is declared unsigned, hence it must not be negative
 /* if m_seq1.size() = 0, then j = -1 : error
```

Also 
As your code suggests, initially u are   assigning matrix[0][i] = i*1;, but then at the loop start only, you are assigning    using ws_cases[0] = matrix[i+1][j+1] + w(m_seq1[j],m_seq2[i]);  if i = 1 j= 1(say), matrix[2][2] is not initialised hence may contain garbage, which may lead segmantation fault or code dump

Comment: i used the gdb debugger and it seems that the error happens at 'ws_cases[0] = matrix[i+1][j+1] + w(m_seq1[j],m_seq2[i]);'

Comment: Hi, as your code suggests, initially u are   assigning matrix[0][i] = i*1;, but then at the loop start only, you are assigning    using ws_cases[0] = matrix[i+1][j+1] + w(m_seq1[j],m_seq2[i]);  if i = 1 j= 1(say), matrix[2][2] is not initialsed hence may contain garbage, which may lead segmantation fault or code dump